# ExcelProvider - writing?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm trying to use the ExcelProvider from http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/ . I'm not sure if I'm missing something here but is there any way to actually write an Excel file?

Comment: no I think you are right and this one is read only (most really are)

Answer (score 3):

For writing I can suggest to try NPOI library: http://fsharp.org/guides/data-science/#excel-interop